# if else return in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

[image]

### Error :

#### Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Unit was expected

> ### code :

```
fun main() {
    val a = 2

    var data: String = if (a != 2) {
        return "Hello"
    } else {
        return "World"
    }

}
```

Comment: "Unit" is the default return type, so that's what main() returns, but you're trying to return a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be like this

```
var data: String = if (a != 2) {
        "Hello"
    } else {
        "World"
    }
```

By using `return` you are returning from the `main` function which has the return type set to "Unit". If you want to display the text, you should then call `println(data)`.

Fun fact, when used like this you can even ignore the "{}" and make it one line like this :

```
var data: String = if (a != 2) "Hello" else "World"
```